# How do you register movement of a finger as a drawing in SwiftUI and check the bounds?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a series of paths that I want a user to draw over and confirm whether or not they indeed wrote over the path or not. Kind of like how some language apps have you write a character and confirm that they wrote the character correctly or not. For example,

```swift
Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 150))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 150))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 400))
        }
```

renders "ㄱ" in Korean. But I'm not sure where to begin, I've looked at `DragGesture` but there's nothing explicit about "drawing with a finger" anywhere that I've seen.

Could anyone shed some light on how drawings by fingers are done with SwiftUI and how one can detect whether it's in the bounds of something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example i just wrote.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var paths: [PathContainer] = []
    @State var currentDraggingId = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background Color for the drawable area
            Color.blue
            
            ForEach(paths) { container in
                // draw and set the foreground color of the paths to red
                container.path
                    .fill(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .gesture(drawGesture)
    }
    
    
    var drawGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { value in
                // The point that the gesture started from
                let start = value.startLocation
                // The point that the gesture ended to
                let end = value.location
                // the properties of the rectangle to be drawn
                let rectangle: CGRect = .init(origin: end,
                                              size: .init(width: start.x - end.x,
                                                          height: start.y - end.y))
                // create a path for the rectangle
                let path: Path = .init { path in
                    path.addRect(rectangle)
                }
                
                // remove the previous rectangle that was drawen in current
                // process of drawing
                paths.removeAll { $0.id == currentDraggingId }
                // append the new rectangle
                paths.append(.init(id: currentDraggingId, path: path))
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                // renew the dragging id so the app know that the next
                // drag gesture is drawing a completely new rectangle,
                // and is not continuing the drawing of the last rectangle
                currentDraggingId = .init()
            }
    }
    
}

// An identifiable container for a path
struct PathContainer: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let path: Path
}
```

[image: final result example]

Comment: amazing, thank you! This helps me a lot in getting started. I wasn't familiar with CGRect

Comment: Happy to know it helped. I was worrying if it was useful since my answer isn't a direct answer. Also removed 2 unnecessary things, 1 the `var lines` and second the `value` in `.onEnded` since both were doing nothing.